# Extract files from content database?

Tags: 2010

My client needs the files from the SharePoint database to be extracted so he can work on the site locally. I have tried sharepoint database extractor and it didn't work, nor did any of the three variants I tried. Is there any simple way that I can just get the files? I have been trying this for three days and would appreciate any help. I am using Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 2):

You should NEVER touch the SharePoint databases directly, at least if you want to keep your solution in a supported state.

What kind of files are we talking about?

Maybee an export / import or backup /restore would do the trick? Since then you would be able to take a copy of your solution and import that into the development environment.

For doing a backup this is the basic script:

```
stsadm -o backup -url http://url/to/site 
       -directory C:\SPBackup -filename mybackup.bak - backupmethod full
```

or the newer Backup-SPSite

```
Backup-SPSite http://url/to/site -Path C:\SPBackup\mybackup.bak
```

(both scripts will backup a specified site collection (but you can use `Backup-SPFarm` to do a backup of the entire farm)

Then use the appropriate restore commands in the new environment like so:

```
Restore-SPSite http://url/to/newsite -Path C:\SPBackup\mybackup.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://plaxoed.wordpress.com/2006/11/02/little-tool-to-extract-all-files-out-of-sharepoint/ for a 2010 environment, not recommended if you plan to actually work on the files though. In my case it was for a decommissioned environment where everything had already been properly migrated to the new environment. The client simply wanted to dump all files on a drive "just because" but actually never use that data again.

Answer (score 0):

You could mount the database into a test web application and extract the files the standard way.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff628582.aspx